# I am not able to locate location drop down(Auto complete) of my application. Below is given code

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get locations from drop down and it is auto complete dropdown and set the location in drop down `loc 2`but i am not able to do it. Using selenium web driver.

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group mb-lg-0">
        <select class="select-site custom-select custom-select-lg select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <option value="0" selected="selected" data-select2-id="14">-- All Sites --</option>
            <option value="35" data-select2-id="15">Loc 1</option>
            <option value="19" data-select2-id="16">Loc 2</option>
        </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--open" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="2" style="width: 250.406px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-k9e1-container" aria-owns="select2-k9e1-results" aria-activedescendant="select2-k9e1-result-bhnd-13"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-k9e1-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="abc">abc</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span>
        </span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--open" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="2" style="width: 250.406px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-k9e1-container" aria-owns="select2-k9e1-results" aria-activedescendant="select2-k9e1-result-bhnd-13"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-k9e1-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="abc">abc</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span>
</span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-k9e1-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-k9e1-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="abc">abc</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span>
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-k9e1-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="abc">abc</span>
<span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
<b role="presentation"></b>
```

Need to automate location drop down.

Comment: Please add your tries also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebElement locationDropdown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[data-select2-id='1']"));
Select select = new Select(locationDropdown);
select.selectByVisibleText("Loc 2");
```